# Is there any way to group by a text column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this code:

```
select CAST(OPERATOR_NAME AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as 'Utilizador',
TERMINAL_DESCRIPTION as 'Terminal',
DOCUMENT_DATE as 'Data de Inicio',
PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE as 'Data de Fim',
ORIGIN_WAREHOUSE_NAME as 'Loja',
DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION as 'Tipos de Documentos' 
from MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER 
GROUP BY CAST(OPERATOR_NAME AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

But it gives me this error:

> Column `MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER.TERMINAL_DESCRIPTION` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

I tried `VARCHAR(100)` and `MAX` but that didn't work either.

How can I get this working?

---

*Updated*

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      Utilizador = OPERATOR_NAME 
    , Terminal = TERMINAL_DESCRIPTION 
    , [Data de Inicio] = DOCUMENT_DATE
    , [Data de Fim] = PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE
    , Loja = ORIGIN_WAREHOUSE_NAME 
    , [Tipos de Documentos] = DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
FROM dbo.MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER
WHERE
       MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER.DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = (@DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION)
    OR MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER.DOCUMENT_DATE = (@DOCUMENT_DATE)
    OR MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER.PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE =(@PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE)
    OR MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER.CORPORATION_ID = (@CORPORATION_ID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT  
      Utilizador = OPERATOR_NAME 
    , Terminal = TERMINAL_DESCRIPTION 
    , [Data de Inicio] = DOCUMENT_DATE
    , [Data de Fim] = PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE
    , Loja = ORIGIN_WAREHOUSE_NAME 
    , [Tipos de Documentos] = DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
FROM dbo.MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER
GROUP BY 
      OPERATOR_NAME
    , TERMINAL_DESCRIPTION
    , DOCUMENT_DATE
    , PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE
    , ORIGIN_WAREHOUSE_NAME
    , DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
        DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
```

Or try more elegant sample -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      Utilizador = OPERATOR_NAME 
    , Terminal = TERMINAL_DESCRIPTION 
    , [Data de Inicio] = DOCUMENT_DATE
    , [Data de Fim] = PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE
    , Loja = ORIGIN_WAREHOUSE_NAME 
    , [Tipos de Documentos] = DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
FROM dbo.MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER
```

*Update for last comment:*

```
SELECT
      Utilizador = OPERATOR_NAME 
    , Terminal = MAX(TERMINAL_DESCRIPTION)
    , [Data de Inicio] = MAX(DOCUMENT_DATE)
    , [Data de Fim] = MAX(PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE)
    , Loja = MAX(ORIGIN_WAREHOUSE_NAME)
    , [Tipos de Documentos] = MAX(DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION)
FROM dbo.MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER
GROUP BY OPERATOR_NAME
```

*Update 2 for last comment:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      Utilizador = OPERATOR_NAME 
    , Terminal = TERMINAL_DESCRIPTION 
    , [Data de Inicio] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DOCUMENT_DATE, 120)
    , [Data de Fim] = PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE
    , Loja = ORIGIN_WAREHOUSE_NAME 
    , [Tipos de Documentos] = DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
FROM dbo.MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER t
WHERE t.DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = @DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
    OR t.DOCUMENT_DATE = @DOCUMENT_DATE
    OR t.PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE = @PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE
    OR t.CORPORATION_ID = @CORPORATION_ID
```

Comment: I really liked this solution i only don't want to repeat the OPERATOR_NAME (sorry for not mentioning it before)

Comment: @Devart it has alot of rows of data. For example OPERATOR_NAME has Name_LastName repeated alot of times. But i guess it is impossible, cause each one has a bond with DOCUMENT_DATE and this collumn has different values for each OPERATOR_NAME.

Comment: Think to SQL Server as a tool to extract the data you need using a SELECT. Then you decide how to display your data with report builder.

Comment: @tezzo i display my data on a table by using the metod SELECT (in the example above) . Than I created a filter (i updated above) in MS SQL RB

Comment: @Devart Yeah, i'm sorry for not providing that much information about it, but what i really wanted was that first code you gave me so it was really helpful! I tried out on MS SQL Server RB and it worked ^^ .

Comment: @Devart, maybe I misunderstood Miguel's question but I think he wants to display every operator access grouped by operator (op1: list of x access; op2: list of y access; etc.). So if you use MAX and GROUP BY OPERATOR_NAME you obtain only one record for operator.

Comment: @tezzo that's right, that's why i used his second sheet of code ^^ . It worked really well. You are both helping me alot x) !

** Btw, do you know how i can return only (YYYY-MM-DD) from DOCUMENT_DATE? It gives me the time aswell (HH-MM-SS)

Comment: @Miguel Matos, try to use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DOCUMENT_DATE, 120)`

Comment: @MiguelMatos, so the solution I think is using the simple SELECT provided by Devart (the one without GROUP BY CLAUSE) and then grouping by OPERATOR_NAME using MS SQL Report Builder (I never used it; see this page for more info http://www.packtpub.com/article/report-builder-in-microsoft-sql-server-2008-part1; search 'column group' in the page)

Comment: If you decide to use Report Builder you can format your date when displayed on report. I think using YourDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") will work: http://forums.asp.net/t/1851875.aspx/1

Comment: Never 'played' with Report Builder: open another question on SO! ;) Just a note: YourDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") is not intended to be used in SQL Server! Maybe in Report Builder you can use it in field/textbox properties/events.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put those columns in a `GROUP BY` clause. It will solve your problem. Just use the below code:

```
select CAST(OPERATOR_NAME AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as 'Utilizador',
TERMINAL_DESCRIPTION as 'Terminal',
DOCUMENT_DATE as 'Data de Inicio',
PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE as 'Data de Fim',
ORIGIN_WAREHOUSE_NAME as 'Loja',
DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION as 'Tipos de Documentos' 
from MRD_DOCUMENT_HEADER 
GROUP BY
  CAST(OPERATOR_NAME AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
  TERMINAL_DESCRIPTION, DOCUMENT_DATE,
  PAYMENT_LIMIT_DATE,
  ORIGIN_WAREHOUSE_NAME,
  DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Sorry i'm kinda new to this stuff and by the way, thanks alot for the fast response! Can you show me an example please? (:

Comment: See whenever you group by using something, whatever the column names are there in the select statement, usually they are included into the group by clause. Just have a look in the above query, i have corrected it. If you face any issue, do let me know.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `GROUP BY` clause in your SQL, then in SELECT list you can only use the same columns that were used in `GROUP BY`, and any other columns **must** be wrapped in aggregate functions like `count()`, `min()`, `max()`, `avg()`, etc.

This is requirement of SQL92/SQL99. However, some SQL engines are very forgiving, for example MySQL and SQLite allow to break this rule. But MS SQL Server, Oracle and PostgreSQL are rather strict.

Answer (score 0):

In this SELECT seems to be only alphanumeric value so you can set ORDER BY OPERATOR_NAME.

The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns (MIN, MAX, COUNT).